# Error in Query String.Whitespaces

Tags: javascript, html, browser, web

I am creating a hyperlink to a page

The url is determined by the user input,thus by the querystring

```
<a href='+abc+'&country='+country +'&state='+state+' ></a>;
```

The problem is that the variable state consists of two or more words..
so when i try to click the hyperlink proving the input in the form,only the first word of the state variable is fetched.Browser treats the other as another variable.
example if i input new york as state.
in the state variable only new is saved,asnd the browser treates york as another variable with a blank value `&york=""`

What should I do?

Comment: What is the exact URL that causes this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the illegal characters with [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent);

```
'<a href='+ encodeURIComponent(abc)
 +'&country=' + encodeURIComponent(country)
 +'&state=' + encodeURIComponent(state) + '></a>;
```

Which would, for example, convert `"aaa bbb"` to `"aaa%20bbb"`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always encode the url:
[Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)

Or use some comma-separated string.